# Proc rank alternative in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, sas, proc

I want to convert the below SAS code in PySpark :

SAS:

```
    proc rank data = INP(where = (col= 1)) 
              out = RESULT groups = 3 descending ;
       var Col1
           Col2
           Col3
           Col4;
       ranks R_Col1 F_Col2 M_Col3 O_Col4 ;
    run ;
```

I am trying to achieve the above using below PySpark code but getting error that 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'apply'
PySpark :

```
def grouping(data):
    dec=pd.qcut(data['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4'],3,labels=False)
    data['ranks']=dec
    return data
RESULT =INP.apply(grouping)
```

Would appreciate any help on this !

Thanks

Comment: That's not a pyspark code. You're using `qcut()` from pandas which isn't supported in pyspark. That said, there are other ways to achieve what you want. Check out the pyspark function documentation for more info. You'd like to go through the ntile or rank there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the below solution :-

```
RESULT = sqlContext.sql(
"""
SELECT  *,
     ntile(3) OVER (order by Col1 desc) AS R_Col1,
     ntile(3) OVER (order by Col2 desc) AS F_Col2,
     ntile(3) OVER (order by Col3 desc) AS M_Col3,
     ntile(3) OVER (order by Col4 desc) AS O_Col4
FROM INP
WHERE col=1
"""
)
```